# Have android Notification open new activity

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I have two Android notifications that get started from my main (not at the same time) and each with a different string in the title field. When creating each of them, I set them up to open to another activity called `ResultActivity` with a textView. I then want to set the textView to say the string in the title field from the notification. I feel like I had it working, but I'm testing it now, and the newer activity always has it's title set, no matter which on you click. Hope that makes some sense.

Snipet from my main:

```
resultIntent.putExtra("title", pass);
```

Snippet from ResultActivity.java:

```
title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
```

The code works, but when I have more than one notification, it seems like the `.putExtra("title", pass)` get's overridden. Does anyone know if that's how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must make the pending intents differ more than in extras. If they are otherwise equal, the system will treat them as the same.

Comment: How so? Also, I mentioned that I felt like it worked before... but are you sure the second is overriding the first?

Comment: Look at this from the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#filterEquals(android.content.Intent)

Comment: Hmm... still intimidated by the documentation... but does it have to do with explicit and implicit intents?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by explicit and implicit intents, but it has to do with how the PendingIntents are handled by the system. All you get is a token that refers to an intent. If that intent already exists (no matter the extras), you get that one. Then you can play with the different flags such as ONE_SHOT to remove an intent after it has been fired, or UPDATE_CURRENT if you do like to replace the extras, and so on.

Comment: Hm... I guess I just need to figure out how to make multiple intents

Comment: Different data uris wil do it. You can even encode the text in the uri.

Comment: Sorry, you're losing me. Encoding the text in the uri?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18257/discussion-between-eghdk-and-tobias-ritzau)

Comment: Search my other questions for the answer given by Tobias.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the newer activity still contains the title from the one you clicked first? Try settings the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` on your PendingIntent to ensure a new task is started.

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notificationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: Doing this, only the newest notification opens up an activity. The first notification seems to do nothing